# Drone Delivery Scheduling Service

Tags: c#, interview-questions

I recently did a interview with WalmartLabs. I was tasked with a take home assignment. I didn't sign a NDA and a team at WalmartLabs said I could post the code on GitHub. I was tasked with developing a program that would deliver orders in such a way to maximize customer satisfaction. My approach to solve this problem was to use a priority queue. The priority queue would prioritize by order created date and distance from the target. Admittedly, I made a mistake by not considering the total passing time when prioritizing orders. I want to become a better developer. I would like to know if someone could look at my github project at https://github.com/vaughnshaun/Walmart_DroneChallenge and tell me any flaws and/or good points of my design. Below is a snippet of a main class for my program. The full project is at my github. The spec for the project is in a pdf named DroneDeliveryChallengeSpec.pdf.

```
public class OrderDeliverer
{
    private List<DeliveredOrder> completedOrders = new List<DeliveredOrder>();
    private IOrderStreamer orderStreamer;
    private Warehouse warehouse;
    private Double promoters;
    private Double detractors;
    private Action<DeliveredOrder> deliveredOrderAction;

    public OrderDeliverer(Warehouse warehouse, IOrderStreamer orderStreamer)
    {
        this.warehouse = warehouse;
        this.orderStreamer = orderStreamer;
    }

    public virtual void ProcessOrder()
    {
        // Artificially advance the time to the next order waiting to be created
        // This is a fail safe, just in case the the processing of orders don't advance time enough
        if (!warehouse.HasOrders)
        {
            orderStreamer.AdvanceTime();
        }

        // Keep processing orders while there are orders
        if (warehouse.HasOrders)
        {
            Order order;

            // If there isn't time for delivery the order should be moved to next day delivery
            if (!warehouse.HasTimeToDeliverNextOrder(orderStreamer.CurrentTime))
            {
                warehouse.MoveNextOrderToNextDay();
            }
            else if (warehouse.TrySendNextOrder(out order)) // Try to send the order out of the warehouse
            {
                // Create a delivered order and track its status and times
                DeliveredOrder outboundOrder = new DeliveredOrder(order.Id);
                outboundOrder.OrderPlaced = order.Created;
                outboundOrder.DepartureTime = orderStreamer.CurrentTime;
                outboundOrder.DeliveredTime = outboundOrder.DepartureTime;

                // Time traveled to the destination
                double travelMinutes = warehouse.GetOrderDeliveryMinutes(order);
                outboundOrder.DeliveredTime = outboundOrder.DeliveredTime.AddMinutes(travelMinutes);

                // Total time traveled, includes to destination and returning back to the warehouse 
                travelMinutes += warehouse.GetOrderReturnMinutes(order);

                completedOrders.Add(outboundOrder);
                deliveredOrderAction(outboundOrder);

                switch (outboundOrder.GetRating())
                {
                    case OrderHelper.RatingType.Detractor:
                        detractors++;
                        break;

                    case OrderHelper.RatingType.Promoter:
                        promoters++;
                        break;
                }

                warehouse.DockDrone();

                // Update the mock global time (will also bring more new orders depending on the time)
                orderStreamer.AddMinutesToTime(travelMinutes);
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnDeliveredOrder(Action<DeliveredOrder> deliveredAction)
    {
        deliveredOrderAction += deliveredAction;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The number of orders successfully delivered
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns an int for the count of delivered orders</returns>
    public int GetNumberOfCompleted()
    {
        return completedOrders.Count;
    }

    public double GetNps()
    {
        double nps = 0;

        if (completedOrders.Count > 0)
        {
            double promoterPercent = (promoters / completedOrders.Count) * 100;
            double detractorPercent = (detractors / completedOrders.Count) * 100;
            int decimalPlaces = 2;

            nps = Math.Round(promoterPercent - detractorPercent, decimalPlaces);
        }

        return nps;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some basic considerations to make in your design.

#### Guard arguments

Perform at least *NotNull* checks on arguments on public entrypoints of your API.

> ```
> public OrderDeliverer(Warehouse warehouse, IOrderStreamer orderStreamer)
>     {
>         this.warehouse = warehouse;
>         this.orderStreamer = orderStreamer;
>     }
> ```

```
public OrderDeliverer(Warehouse warehouse, IOrderStreamer orderStreamer)
    {
        if (warehouse == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(warehouse));
        if (orderStreamer== null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(orderStreamer));
        this.warehouse = warehouse;
        this.orderStreamer = orderStreamer;
    }
```

#### Avoid nesting statements if you can

Code reads easier with the amount of nested statements kept to a minimum.

> ```
> if (!warehouse.HasOrders)
> {
>     orderStreamer.AdvanceTime();
> }
>
> // Keep processing orders while there are orders
> if (warehouse.HasOrders)
> {
>     // code when HasOrders ..
> }
> ```

```
if (!warehouse.HasOrders)
{
    orderStreamer.AdvanceTime();
    return;
}

// Keep processing orders while there are orders
// code when HasOrders ..
```

#### Avoid redundant comments

Comments should be added only if they add substantial new information to the code.
In the above snippet, you could do without

> `// Keep processing orders while there are orders`

#### Inline variable declaration

This can be written in a more concise fashion.

> ```
>  Order order;
>  else if (warehouse.TrySendNextOrder(out order))
> ```

```
else if (warehouse.TrySendNextOrder(out Order order))
```

#### Redundant variable type

The declared type does not need to be printed out when it can be derived logically from the instantiated type.

> `DeliveredOrder outboundOrder = new DeliveredOrder(order.Id);`

```
  var outboundOrder = new DeliveredOrder(order.Id);
```

#### Event lifetime management

Do you have a way to unsubscribe from the event? **This is the cause of many memory leaks.**

> `travelMinutes += warehouse.GetOrderReturnMinutes(order);`

#### Property vs Method

[How to decide?](http://firebreaksice.com/csharp-property-vs-method-guidelines/) Consider using a property for a simple getter `GetNumberOfCompleted`.

#### Virtual methods

Declare virtual methods when there is a use case for it. What is the reason you declare your method virtual?

> `public virtual void ProcessOrder(`

Comment: I agree 100%. These are some really good suggestions that I will implement. For the event lifetime I think you must be referring to deliveredOrderAction and not travelMinutes. I do have to unsubscribe for that.The nested if statement is a good catch because my service will recall the method anyways. As for  ProcessOrder, it is virtual because of unit testing. Even though I didn't get the job, I plan to keep improving this project for others and my own improvement. If you would like to contribute feel free to join the full project at my github.